# VHDL Knight Rider

Tags: fpga, vhdl, clock, counter, shift-register

I am newbie in VHDL. In my code, everything seems right but code doesn't work properly. I couldn't find where my fault is. Any solutions?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Knight_Rider is
port    (
        in_CLK:  in     std_logic;
        out_LED: out    std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
        );
end entity;

architecture Behavioral of Knight_Rider is

signal shift_reg:   std_logic_vector (9 downto 0):= "0000000001";
signal counter:     std_logic_vector (19 downto 0);
signal i:           integer range 0 to 9;
signal res:         std_logic:= '0';

begin 
CLOCK:process(in_CLK)
            begin
                if(rising_edge(in_CLK )) then
                        counter <= counter + 1;
                    end if;
                end process;
            process(counter(19))
                begin
                    if(rising_edge(counter(19)))then
                        if (res = '0') then
                            for i in 0 to 8 loop
                                shift_reg(i+1)<= shift_reg (i);
                                    res <= '1';
                            end loop;
                      else 
                            for i in 9 downto 1 loop
                             shift_reg(i-1) <=shift_reg(i);
                              res <= '0';
                    end loop;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
    out_LED <= shift_reg;
end architecture;
```

EDIT: I have changed the code a bit and now runs perfectly.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Karasimsek is

        Port (   CLK : in   STD_LOGIC;
                 LED : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0));

end Karasimsek;

architecture Behavioral of Karasimsek is
         signal shift_reg: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0) := "0000000001";
         signal sayac:      integer range 0 to 50000000;
         signal yonsec:     std_logic:= '0';
         signal pulse:     std_logic:= '0';
 begin

    process( CLK )

          begin
                if(rising_edge(CLK)) then 

                        if (sayac < 50000000) then 

                                sayac <= sayac + 1 ;
                        else

                                sayac <= 0;
                                          pulse <= '1';

                if (pulse = '1') then                         

                    if (yonsec = '0') then

                        shift_reg <= shift_reg (8 downto 0) & '0';

                        if (shift_reg(8) = '1') then

                            yonsec <= '1';

                            end if;

                    elsif (yonsec = '1') then

                        shift_reg <= '0' & shift_reg (9 downto 1);

                            if (shift_reg(1) = '1') then

                                yonsec <= not yonsec;

                        end if;

                    end if;

                end if;

            end if;

        end if;

    end process;

LED <= shift_reg;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Should you post this on a coding / programming stack?

Comment: "code doesn't work properly", ok, great problem description

Comment: What @Pipe means is, we appreciate your coming to us for advice, but our response is only as good as the information we're given.  Could you tell us what you expected your code to do, and then explain what is actually happening?  If there are error messages, that is very helpful.  Cheers.

Comment: I want to flash LEDs respectively (like Knight Rider) but there is no syntax error. The problem is first LED is open and second LED is blinking where others do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used VHDL, but it looks like your `if(res...)else` loop is simply bouncing back and forth.  Think of it this way,

1) Set your start condition (you did that and it looks OK).

2) Use `res` to change the direction of motion.  This means you don't change it every time `counter` has a rising edge (this is causing your blink).  You change it when the first bit or last bit of shift_reg is `1`.  Your starting condition is `0000000001`.  Say the first bit on the left (a zero) is "bit #9" and the last bit on the right (a one) is "bit #0".  `res` should be set to `0` (moving the bit to the left) when "bit #0" is equal to `1`.  It should be set to `1` when "bit #9" is equal to `1`.  You probably shouldn't set `res` in the shift block.  I'd set it independently after the shift is complete.

3) Finally, you need to be sure the *last bit* of each direction is fed into the first bit.  (You could do this programmatically, but a real circuit would have to act this way.)  Again, your starting condition is `0000000001`, which means `res` should be zero.  On each rising edge of `counter` you shift everything to the left one bit **and** you shift that last bit (bit #9) onto bit #0.  In the other direction you're shifting bit #0 onto bit #9.  That's how you keep your zeros in place.  *In other words, store bit 9, loop up 0-8, then assign your stored bit 9 onto bit 0.  In the other direction: store bit 0, loop down 9-1, then assign bit 0 onto bit 9.*

I suspect #2 is your biggest problem.  That's what stopping the register from moving along.

Finally, take a moment to Google "VHDL Johnson Ring Counter."  It's not exactly what you're trying to do, but it's about 90% of it.  It will help you with your code because many of the examples mimic actual shift register designs including your missing feedback loop.

Comment: Thank you dude. I'll try it. I have been trying to do this for 2 days. If I can achieve this, I believe that I can go further :)

Comment: I remember being given this as a lab experiment ( build circuit and software) in 3 hours!! Of 15 teams, ours was the only one that did not flash the "end" leds twice as the direction was reversed - comment from the prof was to get all the other teams to look at what we had done !! And, no I don't have the code any more....

Comment: @SolarMike dude, I wasn't given any lab experiment or duty about VHDL but I push myself to it. Because there is only way to learn anything is pushing harder. BTW, cool story.